# swagger play plugin searching for conf/routes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jetty, war, swagger

I'm using play framework and deploying a war file using the play 2 war plugin(https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/). I'm also using the Swagger Play plugin (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play) to Jetty. The error occurs when I try to launch the app in Jetty. Swagger play plugin tries to search for conf/routes which isnt present. What do I do to resolve this?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'conf/routes' does not exist
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1711)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1748)
at play.routes.compiler.RoutesFileParser$.parse(RoutesFileParser.scala:25)
at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl.<init>(SwaggerPlugin.scala:112)
at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$de7219b8.newInstance(<generated>)
at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
at play.core.server.servlet.WarApplication.<init>(Play2Server.scala:115)
at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.apply(Play2Server.scala:35)
at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextInitialized(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:45)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with conf/routes not being found has been fixed in the latest release of swagger-play-2 1.5.1

```
"io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.1"
```

Comment: Let me check and get back to you